# Swipe navigation with PKRevealController

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a PKRevealController with front and right views. Pan gesture is enabled, so I can open the right view with a swipe - great. Swiping another way doesn't do anything, as it shouldn't, because there's no left controller to open - great. So instead, I want to implement a swipe (left to right) that would trigger my app's back-navigation.

I've added a swipe gesture recognizer to my (front) view controller - nothing happens.

If I setRecognizesPanningOnFrontView:NO on the reveal controller, then my newly added gesture recognizer works - I can navigate back.

So, now it's either one or the other. I want both. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented my own solution. Two solutions actually, as I needed different ones for cases when I allowed and disallowed `PKRevealController` swipe actions.

**Case 1**: `setRecognizesPanningOnFrontView:NO`

This case is quite easy - I simply add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` that calls my `back` method:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *backSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(back)];
[backSwipe setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:backSwipe];
```

**Case 2**: `setRecognizesPanningOnFrontView:YES`

This one is slightly more complicated. In order to avoid gesture recogniser conflict, I had to tap into `PKRevealController`'s gesture recogniser. Of course, I implemented this only when `PKRevealController` does not have a `leftViewController`.

So, I register the class which I want to implement the back swipe navigation as a listener to notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(back:)
                                             name:NOTIFICATION_BACK_SWIPE
                                           object:self];
```

And then in PKRevealController.m file, in `- (void)moveFrontViewRightwardsIfPossible` method, simply post the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_BACK_SWIPE object:[(UINavigationController *)self.frontViewController topViewController]];
```

Here I am passing as notification's object the recipient `UIViewController` itself. I'm doing this so that only that specific `UIViewController` instance reacts to this notification. Otherwise if you had more `UIViewControllers` in the `UINavigationController` stack that are subscribed to receive this notification, they would all cause the `UINavigationController` to `popViewController`, which would result in a random number of steps back while we want this to happen only once.

That's it. Enjoy.